# for property 'og:image:url' of the object is invalid because it contains whitespace characters facebook app

Tags: php, bash, facebook

I've set up a facebook app which give you a random picture from website database when you call the app 
the problem is that when I preform this [Bash command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dE6nv.png) on it, it show this  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68E7W.png)
and here is [my meta graph facebook app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDg7d.png)

and this is the [php random picture function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8XYQ.png)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. If you edit your post accordingly, feel free to tag me and I will remove my downvote.

Comment: How are we supposed to say anything about this, when you blur all the relevant parts in your screenshots? We can’t even see what the actual value of that image URL is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm bluring it because it has just the facebook ID and the accesstoken only nothing more 
and I don't know if you need those to answer my question
is it necessary